# Custom dialog in android not working

Tags: android

I have to implement a custom dialog in my application, But my codes seems not working.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("Hello, this is a custom dialog!");
ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);
```

And this is my layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/layout_root"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:padding="10dp"
              >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
               />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:textColor="#FFF"
              />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the problem you are running into, can't just say that its not working. please describe the problem and if possible provide logcat log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try to use `dialog.Show()`

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using **setContentView()**, get the LayoutInflater, the=n do whatever you want to do with the layout, then add it to the dialog using **setView()** method.

Because in case of AlertDialog, setContentView will not work.

For more information see this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
Dialog listDialog = new Dialog(this);
listDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.picktemplate));
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null, false);
listDialog.setContentView(view);
listDialog.setCancelable(true);

Button list1 = (Button) listDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnList);
listDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would insist not to use `getApplicationContext()` to create the `Dialog` instance rather use Activitys instance to create it.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Activity_Name.this);
```

Also make sure you are calling `dialog.show();` after creating your Dialog.